# Problem of Context in AlertDialogs Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem in my app.

Before everything, sorry for my bad english.

I have a MainActivity with five fragments and a class of functions (FunctionsApp).

In one of the fragments, it's found "OptionsFragment", this fragment have buttons to go the Settings, logout, and others options.

The problems is when inside the fragment (OptionsFragment) I select the button for go to other Activity, after I do back (with its respective finish), in the fragment OptionsFragment I select the button Logout, that call the **FunctionsApp** and show a AlertDialog.

Showed error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@e363980 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Code:

OptionsFragment:

```
package com.kevin.app.activities;

import...

public class OptionsFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FunctionsApp functionsapp = new FunctionsApp(getActivity());

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_options, container, false);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)vista.findViewById(R.id.nav_options_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        return vista;
    }

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_options_logout) {
            functionsapp.logoutAsk();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_options_settings) {
            functionsapp.goSettingsActivity();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

FunctionsApp:

```
    package com.kevin.app.aplicacion;

    import..

    public class FunctionsApp {

    private static Context context;
    public FunctionsApp(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

// logout
    public void logoutAsk() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage(R.string.message_logout_confirm)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.text_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        registerLogout();
                        cleanAllSP();
                        showToast(context.getString(R.string.message_logout_yes));
                        goWelcomeActivity();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.text_nope, null)
                .show();
    }
```

Can help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe what's happening here is that the activity is going through the destruction phase (when you click the back button) and that's when the background thread finishes it's work and tries to show the dialogue you'd wish. Therefore, to rectify this issue, you just need to check if your Activity is going through the phase of being finished before you actually display that dialogue. 
Do the following:

```
if(!((FunctionsApp)context).isFinishing()){
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage(R.string.message_logout_confirm)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.text_yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        registerLogout();
                        cleanAllSP();
                        showToast(context.getString(R.string.message_logout_yes));
                        goWelcomeActivity();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.text_nope, null)
                .show();
}
```